# Excel 2007 VBA run-time error '91' with For Each loop

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I am receiving a run-time error 91.  I know this is usually from not setting a range properly, but I am only referencing a worksheet in this case.  Why am I getting this error?  The code is supposed to create a new column and name it "company name".

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Sheets
    If ws.Name Like "*Sheet*" Then ws.Rows(1).Find("customer_name",LookAt:=xlPart).EntireColumn.Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        ws.Rows(1).Find("customer_name", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(0, -1).Select  >----error here
        ActiveCell.Value = "company name"
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if the worksheet Name is NOT like "*Sheet*" it will still look for customer_name using the second `FIND`, and it most likely will not be found and give you an error when trying to Select something that is not found.

What you need is this:

```
Sub Sample()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Sheets
    If ws.Name Like "*Sheet*" Then

        ws.Rows(1).Find("customer_name", LookAt:=xlPart).EntireColumn.Select

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        ws.Rows(1).Find("customer_name", LookAt:=xlPart).Select  '>----error here
        ActiveCell.Value = "company name"

    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Or another way to re-write the sub would be:

```
Sub Sample()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Sheets

    If ws.Name Like "*Sheet*" Then

        With ws.Rows(1).Find("customer_name", LookAt:=xlPart)

        .EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Value = "company name"

        End With

    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Find` method returns a `Range`, but returns `Nothing` if nothing is found. You need to account for this using `Is Nothing`.

```
    Dim rngFind As Range

    Set rngFind = ws.Rows(1).Find("customer_name", LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
        rngFind.Offset(0, -1).Select
    End If
```

You need to do something similar for the earlier use of `Find`.